# Performance: float vs Float?

Tags: java, performance

I have to store a lot of `float` in an array. There should be gaps in the array in which no values are stored (at least temporary).

My solution is to make an array of the wrapper class `Float` and set the gaps to `null`. Its clear that this is slower than to deal with a `float`-array but there it is not possible to set to `null`.

Now my question: How big is the performance decrease (time and memory) when taking `Float` instead of `float`?

**SOLUTION:** Use `float` and set gaps to `NaN` with `Float.NaN`

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: `Float.NaN` gives you a `float` that won't appear when calculating with proper values, so it makes a good dummy value.

Comment: I think you should look into a sparse array library. Just Google it.

Comment: I use for this `Float.NaN` with `public static boolean isGap(final float val) { return Float.isNaN(val); }`. There are 3 special values Not a Number, -Infinity, +Infinity

Comment: Are you looking for a rough idea or hard data?  If you're looking for hard data you could code up a quick approximation of your scenario and use a profiler on it to see what it looks like I suppose.